# Dotnet CORE Entity framework - How to reference one list of Suburbs that need to be seeded in two separate databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two databases and I am using the Repository Pattern. Each database has a State and Suburb entity. They are identical but in different databases. There names are identical eg "State" etc.

I want to use the following to seed each database:

```
public static class Seeds
{
    public static IEnumerable<State> States = new State[]
    {
        new State { StateName = "New South Wales", StateShortName = "NSW" },
        ⋮
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Suburb> Suburbs = new Suburb[]
    {
        new Suburb { PostCode = "200", SuburbName = "Australian National University", StateId = stateID, Latitude = -35.2777, Longditude = 149.1189 },
        ⋮
    }
}

public class APIDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        ⋮
        modelBuilder.Entity<State>().HasData(Seeds.States);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Suburb>().HasData(Seeds.Suburbs);
    }
}
```

However I do not want to identical state lists and two identical suburb lists. The suburb list is 16000 odd lines long.

I don't want to create a third database and I don't want two identical lists (maintaining two lists is a bad idea)... I want one list of suburbs and one list of states that both databases can use.

I am not sure how to use the same list in two different databases?

Answer (score 0):

A relational database cannot guarantee integrity (using foreign key) between tables on different servers.

A way to reach your idea would be to refactor your domain splitting it in two DbContext, one for States and other for Suburb (you will loose the foreign key integrity).

```
public static class StatesSeed
{
    public static IEnumerable<State> States = new State[]
    {
        new State { StateName = "New South Wales", StateShortName = "NSW" },
        // ...
    }
}


public static class SuburbsSeed
{
    public static IEnumerable<Suburb> Suburbs = new Suburb[]
    {
        new Suburb { PostCode = "200", SuburbName = "Australian National University", StateId = stateID, Latitude = -35.2777, Longditude = 149.1189 },
        // ...
    }
}

public class StatesDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<State>().HasData(Seeds.States);
        // ...
    }
}


public class SuburbsDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Suburb>().HasData(Seeds.Suburbs);
        // ...
    }
}
```